# Invoke-Sqlcmd there is already an object named _ in the database

Tags: sql, sql-server, powershell

I am running a PowerShell script which creates a DB and a single table with it as below:

```
    Invoke-Sqlcmd -Query @"
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT name FROM master.sys.databases WHERE name = N'ADDB')
    CREATE DATABASE[ADDB]
    GO
    IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'dbo' AND TABLE_NAME = N'UserData')
    BEGIN        
        CREATE TABLE ADDB.dbo.UserData (
            SamAccountName varchar(255) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
            TeamName varchar(255) NULL,
            BuildingName varchar(255) NULL
        );        
    END
"@
```

When I run this the first time everything goes fine and I get no error. But if I run this again it give me the following error:

> There is already an object named 'UserData' in the database.

The rest of of the script and subsequent invoke-sqlcmds run fine and the table gets updated properly. To me it almost looks like as it is ignoring the second "IF NOT EXISTS".

If I run this within SQL Server Management Studio 2012 first time it will say that the command run successfully; as I would have expected.

Second time I would have expected the same as to me the CREATE TABLE clause only runs if the table does not exists. In this is second case it does exist but I get the following error:

> Msg 2714, Level 16, State 6, Line 8 There is already an object named
>   'UserData' in the database.

So the only thing I have concluded here is that the problem definitely lies with the way I have coded my query.

Any suggestions on how I can resolve this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're never changing the database context, so it's looking at `INFORMATION_SCHEMA` in whichever database you started in (probably `master`?)

Comment: I have now modified the IF statement so it reads ...SELECT * FROM ADDB.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES.... and this seems to have resolved the issue. Many thanks for your help.